# Light switch on Shabbat - no bulb, unplugging an extension cord

Tags: halacha, shabbat, electricity

Muktza aside - Is it permissible on Shabbat to turn off a light switch if the light bulb burned out; Is there any issue in removing the current from the circuit 10, 15, 20 ft back?
The same I would imagine would be disconnecting an extension cord on Shabbos that had nothing plugged into it - would that be allowed?

Comment: is this going to cause other lights to go brighter?

Comment: @Draizy-Levi Pine Very often when a plug is removed from an outlet (socket) which has electricity flowing in it,  a tiny spark is emitted which is created by the metal of the plug-prongs rubbing against the metal prong-receivers inside the powered outlet. I'm not sure if this always happens or only sometimes, and if so based on what factors. Creating this spark, even if unintentional, may be considered *psik raisha* (an unintended act which must happen) and therefore one might not be allowed to remove a plug from an outlet.

Comment: @orangesandlemons I can not imagine unplugging an extension cord would impact any other lights.

Comment: @ribbisrabbiandmore I think that spark would only be if you complete or break a circuit with a load on it, ie a working lightbulb

Comment: @Draizy-LeviPine not necessarily, just like if someone touches the inside of an empty light socket they get an electric shock if its plugged in even with no bulb.

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore That’s only if they touch both the positive and the negative at the same time, closing the circuit - touching one at a time would not shock you. Similarly, plugging in an extension cord or unplugging never completes a circuit

Comment: IIRC the Shmiras Shabbos Kehilchato allows one to move objects plugged into the wall, as they are part of a building and thus cannot be Muktzeh. So unplugging would be _demolishing_. I'll try look it up...

Comment: What does the fact that something is not muktzeh have anything to do with soser?